# How to save MapViews and OverlayItems in a bundle?

Tags: android, android-mapview, bundle

I want to keep a MapView and its markers after orientation changes. I have looked through the [Android Bundle Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) and still haven't found anything.

Am I reading the reference material wrong? How would a bundle work for a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

We use `Bundle` class to pass data from one `Activity` to another. In other hand, to get the data that one `Activity` has passed from the current Activity. You can see a simple example of how to use `Bundle` class in [this link](http://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/03/07/how-to-get-the-content-that-user-type-in-a-edittext-field-in-one-activity-to-another-activity-in-android/).

In your question you have to look [Android Run-time Changes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html).

If you are not trying to change data that has in previous view after the orientation change, the simple way is using the **Manifest** file to handle your orientation, like in following code.

```
<activity
    android:name=".WebViewActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" >
</activity>
```